# How to rewrite create_function into an arrow function in PHP

Tags: php, php-7.4

I have a simple code with `create_funtion` which I want to change in the anonymous arrow function.

```
$string = '3.2*2+1';
$compute = create_function("", "return (" . $string . ");" );
var_dump($compute());
```

How to extract logic from `create_funtion` to write it using an arrow notation?

Comment: What are you going to do when someone submits a string of `exec('rm -rf /')`?

Comment: I'm parsing the string before it's passed to `create_function`.

Comment: Blindly evaluating strings as code like this is a horrible, horrible idea. [You should parse the string and evaluate it using definite code.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expression-evaluation/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an arrow function `$string` will be available in the function scope:

```
$compute = fn() => eval("return $string;");
var_dump($compute());
```

Or to use an argument:

```
$compute = fn($s) => eval("return $s;");
var_dump($compute($string));
```

As with `create_function`:

> **Caution**
> This function internally performs an eval() and as such has the same security issues as eval(). Additionally it has bad performance and memory usage characteristics.
>
> If you are using PHP 5.3.0 or newer a native anonymous function should be used instead.

The same cautions with `eval`:

> **Caution**
> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

As already commented be aware that everithing you pass in $string is eval'ed and it's a potential threat to your code

You can do something like this: (Closure, compatible with php < 7.4 )

```
$string = '3.2*2+1';
$compute = function() use ($string) { return eval("return $string;"); };
var_dump($compute());
```

Arrow function (php >= 7.4)

```
$string = '3.2*2+1';
$compute = fn() => eval("return $string;");
var_dump($compute());
```

Comment: Moreover, but I'll leave in comments just to "limit" the advertising to something weird and to avoid since intrinsecally insecure...I've created a sort of polyfill for create_function here https://github.com/lombax85/create_function

Comment: How it differs from `eval($string");`?

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Tulikowski It creates a function that can be passed around and called multiple times.

Comment: a simple `eval($string)` will simply try to eval `3.2*2+1` which will lead in first instance to a parse error (lack of ; at the end), if you add ; it won't do nothing (you are not returning the result)

Comment: If you use an arrow function you don't need `use($string)`

Comment: @Barmar you are right, I used a closure (I have some project in php 7.3 and use closures for compatibility reasons). I update the answer